# How can I create the root administration user root:rootroot for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, configuration, root

I am creating a Software configuration for **MySQL 5.6.22** and I'll need to create the root administration user `root:rootroot`.

Next step, I'll need to install as service/daemon with auto-start option and finally this installation needs:

- MySQL Workbench 6.2.4
- MySQL Connector/J 5.1.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure the Data Base on RNL Lab of the project the programmer shell do:

The `mysql -uroot -p` try to connect to the server and it won't have access to it.

The programmer shell always use `mysql-local-client`, this might work as an alias to the root, while the pass maintains the same as "root".

1. For running the project it must be started by the MySQL Server on the working Computer:

`mysql-local-start`

At the end it might encounter the running server port (should be the 10000 or 10001).

2. After that it must have a connection to the server, using other command line, to creating the user, give the right privilege and finally for creating the Data Base with:

`mysql-local-client`

It's necessary to use this command, that works as an alias for the last server created.

3. Please run the next commands on MySQL Shell from the mysql-local-client:

`CREATE USER 'bubble'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bubbl3';`

`CREATE USER 'bubble'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'bubbl3';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bubbledb.* TO 'bubble'@'localhost';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bubbledb.* TO 'bubble'@'%';`

`CREATE DATABASE bubbledb;`

4. At last it needed to change the properties for the Fenix Framework so that the next code runs (where 10000 is the running server port):

`dbAlias=//localhost:10000/bubbledb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;clobCharacterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

`dbUsername=bubble`

`dbPassword=bubbl3"`